# How to pin app design taskbar to the bottom in Adobe Experience Design?

Tags: adobe-xd

How to pin app design taskbar to the bottom in Adobe Experience Design, so when doing vertical scroll, it stays pinned to the bottom and always visible?

Answer (score 1):

*Update:* This feature was added in XD's June 2018 update. To mark an element as non-scrolling, select the element and go to Prototype mode:

[image: XD mode "tabs"]

Then select "Fix Position When Scrolling" in the properties panel:

[image: "Fix Position When Scrolling" checkbox]

Be sure your fixed/pinned element is positioned "above the fold" in the artboard, otherwise it will never be visible at all.

---

*(original answer)*
<s>This isn't possible in Adobe XD yet — currently, the entire contents of the artboard will all scroll. You can upvote [the official feature request](https://adobexd.uservoice.com/forums/353007/suggestions/13031847-fixed-elements-in-scrolling-artboards-header-nav) to raise its priority, and then you'll also get email notifications when its status changes.</s>